# Loop over several excel files to create different dataframes, perform group by and save as a single df in R

Tags: r, excel, dataframe

I am new in R and I have a doubt, in case you can help.

I have several excel files in one folder. They belong to different filials but have the same structure.
I would like to loop over them, load into R as a dataframe, perform a group by and save everything in a single dataframe and export as a single file. Would this be possible?

By looking at several answers here I did this:

```
# Load the data as different dataframes

library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)

f <- list.files(pattern="xlsx")

myfiles = lapply(f, read_excel)


for (i in 1:length(f)) assign(f[i], read_excel(f[i], sheet = "Deutsch", skip=7), data.frame(f[i]))
```

I have them saved as single dataframes, I don't know how to access them all together, so I manually created a list:

```
list_df = list(filialAA.xlsx, filialAB.xlsx,filianAC.xlsx,filianAD.xlsx,filianAE.xlsx...etc)
```

Then I created a group by to perform some calculations:

```
for (i in 1:length(list_df))
{
  list_df[i] %>% 
    group_by(ABC) %>% 
    summarise(`Revenue in EUR` = sum(`Revenue in EUR`),
              `Weight in KG` = sum(`Weight in KG`),
              `Number of Materials` = length(`Materials`),
              `Avg of deliveries` = mean(`Deliveries`))
}
```

If I do this for each dataframe, it works. But inside this loop it does not.
Could you help me to loop over all dataframes, perform this group by and gather together in one single file? Is it possible?

Thanks a lot for your attention!

EDIT: To include a dummy data sample:

```
> dput(df1)

structure(list(Materials = c("11575358", "75378378", "21333333", 
"02469984", "05465478", "05645648"), Deliveries = c(8, 1, 12, 
5, 1, 1), ABC = c("C", "A", "C", "B", "C", "C"), `Revenue in EUR` = c(6179, 
1804802.46, 3768.04, 9e+05, 1597.5, 1544.55), `Weight in KG` = c(16.6, 
4.695625, 19, 9.14625, 2.74041666666667, 1.44208333333333)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

> dput(df2)

structure(list(Materials = c("48654798", "05465489", "04598496", 
"08789453", "01589494", "06459849", "54694985", "65498848"), 
    Deliveries = c(24, 6, 32, 3, 11, 30, 45, 2), ABC = c("C", 
    "B", "C", "B", "C", "A", "A", "C"), `Revenue in EUR` = c(5509, 
    506978, 3978.04, 7e+05, 1597.5, 1200258, 2406975, 4059), 
    `Weight in KG` = c(29.6, 19, 24, 9.14625, 2.74041666666667, 
    50, 60, 10)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Original excel is xlsx format, have from 5000 to 15000 rows, about 20 features, 7 tabs. There are 22 excel files to loop over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it could have some error due I have not your files, but try something like this:

```
# first of, write down your files in xlsx. I use xlsx because I prefere it
#but you should already have them
xlsx::write.xlsx2(df1,"df1.xlsx")
xlsx::write.xlsx2(df1,"df2.xlsx")

library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)

# here you get all the xlsx files
f <- list.files(pattern="xlsx")  
f
[1] "df1.xlsx" "df2.xlsx"

# an empty list
listed <- list()
# loop that populate the empty list with your files
for (i in f) { 
  listed[[i]] <- read_excel(i, sheet = "Sheet1" # , skip = 7  
                            )
  print(paste0("read the", i," file")) # here it says what it's doing
}

 listed
$df1.xlsx
# A tibble: 6 x 6
  ...1  Materials Deliveries ABC   `Revenue in EUR` `Weight in KG`
  <chr> <chr>          <dbl> <chr>            <dbl>          <dbl>
1 1     11575358           8 C                6179           16.6 
2 2     75378378           1 A             1804802.           4.70
3 3     21333333          12 C                3768.          19   
4 4     02469984           5 B              900000            9.15
5 5     05465478           1 C                1598.           2.74
6 6     05645648           1 C                1545.           1.44

$df2.xlsx
# A tibble: 6 x 6
  ...1  Materials Deliveries ABC   `Revenue in EUR` `Weight in KG`
  <chr> <chr>          <dbl> <chr>            <dbl>          <dbl>
1 1     11575358           8 C                6179           16.6 
2 2     75378378           1 A             1804802.           4.70
3 3     21333333          12 C                3768.          19   
4 4     02469984           5 B              900000            9.15
5 5     05465478           1 C                1598.           2.74
6 6     05645648           1 C                1545.           1.44

# now lapply to each element of the list, the summary, creating a new list
list_result <- lapply(listed, function(x) x %>% 
                                          group_by(ABC) %>% 
                                          summarise(
                          `Revenue in EUR` = sum(`Revenue in EUR`),
                          `Weight in KG` = sum(`Weight in KG`),
                          `Number of Materials` = length(`Materials`),
                          `Avg of deliveries` = mean(`Deliveries`)))

# put the result in a data.frame  
do.call(rbind,list_result)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  ABC   `Revenue in EUR` `Weight in KG` `Number of Materials` `Avg of deliveries`
* <chr>            <dbl>          <dbl>                 <int>               <dbl>
1 A             1804802.           4.70                     1                 1  
2 B              900000            9.15                     1                 5  
3 C               13089.          39.8                      4                 5.5
4 A             1804802.           4.70                     1                 1  
5 B              900000            9.15                     1                 5  
6 C               13089.          39.8                      4                 5.5
```

Comment: @jessirocha does one of the answers helps you or you need further explainations?

Comment: Hi  @s__. Thanks for your answer. I get errors with both answers and I don't know how to fix it. So i am doing all manually. With your anwer, the problem is with the Group_by method " Fehler in UseMethod("group_by") : 
  nicht anwendbare Methode für 'group_by' auf Objekt der Klasse "character" angewendet " . I read in some places that maybe installing dplyr would help and so I did, but the error persists...
I also used group_by when I posted this question and it was working, so I am not sure what the problem is now

Comment: If you share an excerpt of one of your xlsx (import one, do dput(head(file))) and post the result in your question I'll can to mimic your data and give a better answer.

Comment: I create a dummy sample file. I am not allowed to share the original one, but I tried to keep the format. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @jessirocha thanks, but unluckily it's not recommended to share file to download, here we are strangers, and it could non be safe for our pc. I advice you to simply create a dummy data.frame as your xlsx and post a dput(head(your_df)) here. We'll create ourselves some fake .xlsx based on your data (it's important that colnames are the same). Also, you need to take multiple sheet from multiple .xlsx?

Comment: I updated again. No, I have multiple sheets but I only need to select one for my calculation. It is always the same sheet.

Comment: @jessirocha see edits, it should work now.

Answer (score 1):

You may also use `purrr::map` suitably

```
map_dfr(list_df, ~(. %>% 
    group_by(ABC) %>% 
    summarise(`Revenue in EUR` = sum(`Revenue in EUR`),
              `Weight in KG` = sum(`Weight in KG`),
              `Number of Materials` = length(`Materials`),
              `Avg of deliveries` = mean(`Deliveries`))))
```

It will `rbind` the results simultaneously.

Even after storing files in `myfiles` you can use the following syntax

```
library(janitor)
map_dfr(myfiles, ~(.[-c(1:5),] %>% row_to_names(1) %>% 
                     group_by(ABC) %>% 
                     summarise(`Revenue in EUR` = sum(as.numeric(`Revenue in EUR`)),
                               `Weight in KG` = sum(as.numeric(`Weight in KG`)),
                               `Number of Materials` = length(`Materials`),
                               `Avg of deliveries` = mean(as.numeric(`Deliveries`)))
                   %>% ungroup()))
```

results with your given files

```
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  ABC   `Revenue in EUR` `Weight in KG` `Number of Materials` `Avg of deliveries`
  <chr>            <dbl>          <dbl>                 <int>               <dbl>
1 A             1804802.           4.70                     1                 1  
2 B              900000            9.15                     1                 5  
3 C               13089.          39.8                      4                 5.5
4 A             3607233          110                        2                37.5
5 B             1206978           28.1                      2                 4.5
6 C               15144.          66.3                      4                17.2
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!  The first solution always complains about not being a vector. Fehler: All columns in a tibble must be vectors.
x Column `filianAA.xlsx` is a `fseq/function` object.

The second solution it works in my dummy dataset but in my real one compleins about "Fehler: Must group by variables found in `.data`.
* Column `ABC` is not found.". It is strange because my column is there...

Comment: You should check the `myfiles` in that case.  Can you upload a snapshot its structure.  Actually the method differs in scenario when the list where we want to operate is at some different level than intended.

Answer (score 0):

I like to write functions, so I would do it like this (although longer it creates a more stable environment to modify/debug when required).

```
# Main Function
main_function <- function(import, name){
 main_function.create_path() -> path
 main_function.create_output() -> output
 for(file in list.files(path){
  if(!str_detect(file, 'csv')){
   next
  }
  read_excel(file, sheet = "Deutsch", skip = 7) -> data
  main_function.calculate_values(data) -> data.values
  main_function.append_values(file, data, data.values, output) -> output
 }
 main_function.export(path, output, name)
 if(import){
  assign('values', output, envir = .Globalenv)
 }
}
    
# Functions
main_function.export <- function(path, output, name){
 write.csv(output, file = paste0(path, name, '.csv'))
 }
 
main_function.append_values <- function(file, data, data.values,   output){
 # This will create a row in the output file with the name of the file
 # without the .csv at the end in the first column and put in the 
 # calculated data in the other columns
 str_extract(file, ".+(?=.csv)") -> output[nrow(output) + 1, 'file'] 
 for(col in colnames(data.values)){
   data.values[,col] -> output[nrow(output), col]
 return(output)
 }

main_function.calculate_values <- function(data){
 data %>% group_by(ABC) %>%
  summarize(`Revenue in EUR` = sum(`Revenue in Eur`, na.rm=TRUE),
            ....) -> data
 return(data)
 }
 
main_function.create_path <- function(){
 '<path to files>' -> path
 return(path) 
 }
   
main_function.create_output <- function(){
 data.frame('file' = as.character(NA), 'Revenue in EUR' = 0, 
  'Weight in KG' = 0, 'Number of Materials' = 0, 'Avg of deliveries' = 0) -> output
 return(output)
 }
```

This will create the `main_function` that when called will cycle through all of the files listed in the path given and read it, process it, save it to `output` which which will be saved in the same path with the name you give it.
If you set `import` to TRUE it will also save the output